# What to do with StackedAreaChart rendering bug

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I often encounter a really troublesome bug in StackedAreaChart. Instead of getting

[image]

I get

[image]

The bug seems to rear its head often when data-points-per-display-pixel density is high (though not extraordinarily), non-linear, and/or when successive data series' x-components are not aligned. For example, the two images above are the of the same window, simply resized.

Here is the code that reproduces the bug on Windows 7 32-bit and 64-bit platforms:

```
public class ChartTest extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 100, 10);
    NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 100, 10);
    StackedAreaChart<Number,Number> chart;
    chart = new StackedAreaChart(xAxis,yAxis);
    chart.setLegendVisible(false);
    chart.setCreateSymbols(false);
    chart.getData().add(genSeries(0));
    chart.getData().add(genSeries(1));

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(chart);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private Series<Number,Number> genSeries(int a){
    Series<Number,Number> s = new Series<>();
    ObservableList<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>> d = s.getData();
    for(int i=0; i<50; i++){
        double x = Math.sqrt(2*i+a);
        d.add(new XYChart.Data<>(x, i));
    }
    return s;
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Does anyone know anything about this bug, how to work around it, or under what conditions exactly it appears?

It can get really bothersome:

[image]

Comment: can reproduce in jdk8u20, worksforme in jdk8u40b23 - so looks like a bug that had been fixed in th emeantime

Comment: The problem (or a similar one) seems to be back again to a smaller extent in jdk8u60. Unfortunately it doesn't seem so easy this time to make a simple program that reproduces it.